# Why is this callback being shown as null in this dart method

Tags: dart, flutter

So I have this code in my flutter app - here the function `refreshState` is being called by the method `foo` which is passing in a lambda.However during debugging it says the callback is null. Any ideas why this is happening because of this my callback code is not being executed.

```
     void refreshState(Function callback)
        {
            if(isAlive) {
                setState(() {
                    if (callback != null) {
                        callback;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

at one point in my code I am doing this

```
 void didPush() {
        foo();
    }

void foo()
    {
        refreshState(() {        //<------------------This lambda is showing up as null in the paramter of refreshState
               isBusy = true;
       });
}
```

Any ideas of why this lamda is showing up as null in the `refreshState` function parameter ?

Comment: Well I am passing it exactly exactly like we pass it to setState.

Comment: Check my answer. You can also click on `callback` in the debug view to check its content. `() =>` always means function returning something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misunderstand the debug view here. It is a function `()` returning (`=>`) `null`. You just do not execute it.

```
() => ...
```

This is just a shortcut for:

```
() {
  return ...
}
```

To execute your `callback` you need to add parantheses though. That would be:

```
setState(() {
  if (callback != null)
    callback();
});
```

Comment: Yup that did the trick. Seems like I need to go to bed. I see what I was doing wrong :)